# Why layout folder is not showing in my Android studio project

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin

I just started with Flemingo Android studio by following a few YouTube tutorials. They have activity_main.xml folder but in my laptop it is not showing. Can anyone help?

I tried going through the folders and options present in the project window, went to chatgpt and asked the same, there I found a term called Jetpack Compose, i tried to understand about it but not to its essence. can anyone just help me with this issue?

Comment: if you need to survive in Android Development, start from here https://developer.android.com/courses/android-basics-compose/course

Comment: `activity_main.xml` is a layout file inside the `app/res/layouts` directory of your project. Jetpack Compose is a completely different way of creating a UI and doesn't use layout XML files.